# Subset a string in r using gsub and regexpr

Tags: r, string, expression

I need to change the following

```
test <- c("August 08, 2016, Hour 23",
          "June 26, 2016, Hour 14",
          "November 26, 2016, Hour 01")

test1 <- c("Wednesday:8pm-12pm:31days",
"Tuesday:7pm-10pm:6days|Today:7AM-6PM:7days")
```

Edit:-
In test1, I don't really care much about the day of the week, but am more interested in the timestamp. I would like to see 8PM-12PM converted into 24 hr time format as : 2000 - am agreeable with a string as an output as I require a 4 digit number. (Anything before 10 AM would need to be 0x)

into two datasets as:-

```
a$date <- c(08/08/2016,06/26/2016,11/26/2016) # all in date class
a$hour <- c(23, 14 , 01) #all should be numeric


b$time <- c("2000","1922","0718") #can be character
b$days <- c(31,6,7)  #needs to be numeric
```

The logic for the hour and days cases would be similar. I'm looking to use `gsub` and `regexpr` in R.

My current process for the date section is too long and tedious:-

```
mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(test," ")),ncol=5,byrow=T))

mat$V6 <-  str_replace_all(paste(as.numeric(str_replace_all(mat$V2,"[[:punct:]]","")),
                          "-",as.character(mat$V1),
                          "-",as.numeric(str_replace_all(mat$V3,"[[:punct:]]",""))),
                          "[[:space:]]","")


mat$V7 <- as.Date(mat$V6, format="%d-%B-%Y")

class(mat$V7)

mat$V8 <- as.numeric(as.character(mat$V5))
```

Any suggestions for using `gsub` and `regexpr` in both cases would be appreciated.

Comment: So your solution works but you need someone to review your code and see if they can help you optimize it? There's a whole different StackExchange site just for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This does the same thing as your mat line. Go ahead and try it.

```
library(reshape2)
mat <- colsplit(test," ", c("M","D","YYYY","HR","Time"))
```

I think is your best bet, instead of using gsub or regexpr.

```
mat$Len <- paste(mat$D,mat$M,mat$YYYY)
mat$Len <- gsub(",","",gsub(" ","-",mat$Len))
```

I am not a fan of using nested gsub's but it serves a purpose here. Keeps this a bit more concise. This should take care of the mat$v6 line.